# Распарсить xml в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, xmlparser

Помогите написать функцию которая распарсит кусок xml и загонит элементы в питоновский словарь:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Data>
        <Report>


            <LeaderList>
                <Leader ActualDate="2009-12-01" FIO="Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx" INN="5xxxxxxxxx" Position="генеральный директор"/>
                <Leader ActualDate="2008-10-07" FIO="Вxxxxxx Аxxxxxx Аxxxxxxx" Position="генеральный директор"/>
                <Leader ActualDate="2007-04-17" FIO="Оxxxxxxxx Сxxxxx Вxxxxxxx" Position="генеральный директор"/>
                <Leader ActualDate="2004-12-06" FIO="Кxxxxxxx Аxxxxxxx Нxxxxxx" Position="генеральный директор"/>
            </LeaderList>

        </Report>
    </Data>
    <ResultInfo ExecutionTime="140" ResultType="True"/>
</Response>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы был выбран только ряд c самой поздней датой ActualDate все данные записаны в словарь (Date, FIO, Position). Т.е  в нашем случае - это ряд с ActualDate="2009-12-01"

Написал следующее, но может есть что попроще:

```
def get_ceo(result, tag_list):

current_date = []
for item in tag_list:
    current_date.append(item.attrib['ActualDate'])
    if item.attrib['ActualDate'] == max(current_date):
        result['CEO'] = item.attrib['FIO']
        result['Position'] = item.attrib['Position']
        result['INN_CEO'] = item.attrib['INN']
        result['ActualDate_CEO'] = item.attrib['ActualDate']
```

Comment: Вот вроде же не первый день на стэке. Неужели не привык еще, что просьбы без собственных попыток никак не воспринимаются...

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev вы правы, внес свой вариант, буду признателен за комменнтарий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удобства можно использовать специализированные библиотеки, которые разбирают `xml` в объекты python.

Общие данные:

```
from datetime import datetime

def to_date(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')

text = """\
<Response>
    <Data>
        <Report>
            <LeaderList>
                <Leader ActualDate="2009-12-01" FIO="Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx" INN="5xxxxxxxxx" Position="генеральный директор"/>
                <Leader ActualDate="2008-10-07" FIO="Вxxxxxx Аxxxxxx Аxxxxxxx" Position="генеральный директор"/>
                <Leader ActualDate="2007-04-17" FIO="Оxxxxxxxx Сxxxxx Вxxxxxxx" Position="генеральный директор"/>
                <Leader ActualDate="2004-12-06" FIO="Кxxxxxxx Аxxxxxxx Нxxxxxx" Position="генеральный директор"/>
            </LeaderList>
        </Report>
    </Data>
    <ResultInfo ExecutionTime="140" ResultType="True"/>
</Response>
"""
```

Примеры:

#### [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict):

````
```
# pip install xmltodict
import xmltodict

doc = xmltodict.parse(text)
items = doc['Response']['Data']['Report']['LeaderList']['Leader']

# Находим максимальный элемент через дату
leader = max(items, key=lambda x: to_date(x['@ActualDate']))
print(leader['@FIO'])         # Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx
print(leader['@ActualDate'])  # 2009-12-01
print(leader['@Position'])    # генеральный директор
```
````

#### [untangle](https://github.com/stchris/untangle):

````
```
# pip install untangle
import untangle

doc = untangle.parse(text)
items = doc.Response.Data.Report.LeaderList.Leader

leader = max(items, key=lambda x: to_date(x['ActualDate']))
print(leader['FIO'])         # Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx
print(leader['ActualDate'])  # 2009-12-01
print(leader['Position'])    # генеральный директор
```
````

#### [lxml.objectify](https://lxml.de/objectify.html):

````
```
# pip install lxml
from lxml import objectify

root = objectify.fromstring(text)
items = root.Data.Report.LeaderList.Leader

leader = max(items, key=lambda x: to_date(x.attrib['ActualDate']))
print(leader.attrib['FIO'])         # Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx
print(leader.attrib['ActualDate'])  # 2009-12-01
print(leader.attrib['Position'])    # генеральный директор
```
````

---

Можно делать разбор `XML`, используя парсеры. Опишу некоторые из них:

#### [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/). Метод `select` принимает выражения как `css-селектор`:

````
```
# pip install bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')

items = root.select('Leader')
leader = max(items, key=lambda x: to_date(x['ActualDate']))

print(leader['FIO'])         # Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx
print(leader['ActualDate'])  # 2009-12-01
print(leader['Position'])    # генеральный директор
```
````

Для `BeautifulSoup` можно разные парсеры использовать, например: `xml`, `lxml`, `html.parser`. [Они делятся](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) по типу данных: `XML` или `HTML`, а так же по скорости: `lxml` например очень быстрый.
А если использовать парсер для `html`, то нужно быть внимательным - в HTML регистр тегов и атрибутов неважен (html регистронезависимый), и `bs4` их переводит в нижний регистр:

````
```
root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
items = root.select('leader')
leader = max(items, key=lambda x: to_date(x['actualdate']))

print(leader['fio'])         # Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx
print(leader['actualdate'])  # 2009-12-01
print(leader['position'])    # генеральный директор
```
````

#### [lxml](https://lxml.de/installation.html). Метод `xpath` принимает [xpath-выражение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

````
```
# pip install lxml
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(text)

items = root.xpath('//Leader')
leader = max(items, key=lambda x: to_date(x.attrib['ActualDate']))

print(leader.attrib['FIO'])         # Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx
print(leader.attrib['ActualDate'])  # 2009-12-01
print(leader.attrib['Position'])    # генеральный директор
```
````

#### [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Этот модуль из стандартной библиотеки:

````
```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(text)

items = root.iter('Leader')
# Или:
# items = root.findall('.//Leader')
leader = max(items, key=lambda x: to_date(x.attrib['ActualDate']))

print(leader.attrib['FIO'])         # Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx
print(leader.attrib['ActualDate'])  # 2009-12-01
print(leader.attrib['Position'])    # генеральный директор
```
````

#### [xml.dom.minidom](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Этот модуль из стандартной библиотеки:

````
```
import xml.dom.minidom

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(text)
items = dom.getElementsByTagName('Leader')
leader = max(items, key=lambda x: to_date(x.attributes['ActualDate'].value))

print(leader.attributes['FIO'].value)         # Шxxxxxxx Аxxxxx Шxxxxxx
print(leader.attributes['ActualDate'].value)  # 2009-12-01
print(leader.attributes['Position'].value)    # генеральный директор
```
````

---

**PS.**

А в словарь, думаю, уже сами добавите :)

Comment: Большое спасибо, за такой развернутый ответ! Очень полезно!!!!

Comment: @Pavel, пожалуйста :)